# Multiple excel data storing in Dictionary using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am stuck in one problem and am not able to go ahead.. please need help to move further. 
I have input excel in this format...

[image]

```
Name    usn          Sub   marks
dhdn    1bm15mca13    c     90
                     java   95
                     python 98
subbu   1bm15mca13   java   92
                     perl   91
paddu   1bm15mca13    c#    80
                     java   81
```

And am trying to get expected dictionary in this format:

```
d = [
{
"name":"dhdn",
"usn":1bm15mca13",
"sub":["c","java","python"],
"marks":[90,95,98]
},
{
"name":"subbu",
"usn":1bm15mca14",
"sub":["java","perl"],
"marks":[92,91]
},
{
"name":"paddu",
"usn":1bm15mca17",
"sub":["c#","java"],
"marks":[80,81]
}
]
```

Tried code but it is working for only two column

```
import pandas as pd
existing_excel_file = 'test.xls'

df_service = pd.read_excel(existing_excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1')

df_service = df_service.fillna(method='ffill')
result = [{'name':k,'sub':g["sub"].tolist()} for k,g in df_service.groupby("name")]
print (result)
```

Please provide idea or suggestion to solve my problem.

Comment: Why dont you group by both `name` and `usn`. Then your index will be a tuple. of which one will be name and other will be usn. Also, in the grouped dataframe, you still have all the columns. so `g['marks'].tolist()` will give you the marks list.

Comment: @najeem please can u show how?

Comment: Please paste data that I can use instead of a screenshot. May be after the `ffill`.

Comment: import pandas as pd
existing_excel_file = 'test.xls'
df_service = pd.read_excel(existing_excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df_service = df_service.fillna(method='ffill')
result = [{'name':k,'usn':k,'sub':g["sub"].tolist(),"marks":g["marks"].tolist()} for k,g in df_service.groupby(['name', 'usn'])]
print (result)
I tried this way but here name usn both coming in single key value

Comment: `'name':k[0], 'usn':k[1]`

Comment: Name usn                Sub marks
dhdn 1bm15mca13 c 90
                         java 95
                         python 98
subbu 1bm15mca13  java     92
                           perl      91
paddu 1bm15mca13  c#      80
                           java     81

Comment: Edit your original question and paste the data there. Preferably as a dict or so.

Comment: edited please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
existing_excel_file = 'test.xls'

df_service = pd.read_excel(existing_excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1')

df_service = df_service.fillna(method='ffill')
result = [{'name':k[0],'usn':k[1],'sub':v["sub"].tolist(),"marks":v["marks"].tolist()} for k,v in df_service.groupby(['name', 'usn'])]
pprint (result)
```